# Javascript function incremant automatization problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, momentjs

Below is my function, dotkoy variable: `iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY') == props.activity[0] || iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY') == props.activity[2]` I don't like that, props.activity is array I want to props.activity auto increase to array lenght and I want check `iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY') == props.activity[0]...props.activity[props.acticity.length]`
summarize props.activity array have dates in I want to check the dates one by one with it iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY') in addition times and constant function like loadsh times and constant method. Thanks for any advice

```
Calculate = (props) => {

  const constant = x => () => x;
  const times = (n, iterator) => {
    let accum = Array(Math.max(0, n));
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) accum[i] = iterator.call();
    return accum;
  };
  let result = [];
  const currentMonth = props.focus.month();
  let iterator = moment(props.focus);
  let i = 0;
  let h = 0;
  let control = []
  while (iterator.month() === currentMonth) {
    if (iterator.weekday() === 0 || result.length === 0) {
      result.push(times(7, constant({})));
    }
    let week = result[result.length - 1];
    week[iterator.weekday()] = {
      date: iterator.date(),
      dotkoy: iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY') == props.activity[0] || iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY') == props.activity[2],
      selected: props.selected && iterator.isSame(props.selected, 'day'),
      today: iterator.isSame(moment(), 'day'),
      haftasonumu: iterator.format('ddd') == "Cts" || iterator.format('ddd') == "Paz",
    };
    iterator.add(1, 'day');
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). This will check each member of the array against the callback you give and return `true` if at least one member passes the check or `false` if none do:

```
dotkoy: props.activity.some(activity => iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY') == activity)
```

If you want to avoid doing a linear scan every iteration, you can pre-compute a lookup for all members of `prop.activity` and check against that. The easiest option in this case is a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
const lookupDates = new Set(props.activity);

/* ... */

dotkoy: lookupDates.has(iterator.format('DD-MM-YYYY')),
```